# Does poor grammar on a shared message board for school annoy teachers?

Tags: writing-style, online-learning

From the experience of a student, these are the types of people I notice on class messaging boards:

**Person 1.** Writes almost six-seven paragraphs for a single question that could be asked in two sentences. All sentences are grammatically correct and punctuated. Always includes greeting and salutation.

**Person 2.** Writes about three paragraphs. Most sentences have proper grammar. Either salutation or greeting.

**Person 3.** Writes one or two sentences. Most I's are not capitalized and poor grammar.

**Person 4.** Random letters mixed in, most sentences are gibberish.

Does this annoy teachers? Especially from junior high through high school where this is common.

Most teachers reply even to the most nonsensical messages, which is nice of them, but it is annoying to me (as a student) when someone doesn't take the time and effort to add a period at the end of their sentence.

So, from the perspective of a teacher or professor, are People 3 and 4's (as shown above) behavior on a shared message board obnoxious?

Comment: It isn't an answer to the question, other than that 3 and 4 annoy a lot of people. Extreme abbreviations, as people often use with their close friends while chatting should be reserved for that.

Comment: Question (wordiness) doesn't match the title (grammar) - that might annoy some teachers.

Comment: @MisterMak I'm sorry - that was a typo, I meant to say people *3 and 4* rather than *1 and 2*. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Teachers could very well be annoyed by 3 and 4, but would probably answer nonetheless.  They might also reach out to the poor writers and offer tips.  Posting writing rules for the messaging board in advance might help also.